# Get the list of assets associated to a Solana wallet address

Tags: typescript, solana, solana-web3js

I am using web3 sdk of Solana to query balances or make transactions. Now I would like to know if it's possible to achieve one of the following actions:

1. Get a list of the assets from a provided wallet address.
2. Get a wallet address from a provided nft address. This one will be better if both are possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely, to answer your questions:

1. `getTokenAccountsByOwner`, where the owner is the wallet address: https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#getTokenAccountsByOwner
2. `getTokenLargestAccounts` will give the holders for the nft: https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#getTokenLargestAccounts